# Result of a Query in One Column on Another Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a report that shows attendance at a weekly class. We use an electronic check-in system so each person's info is saved with a date into the database.

I can easily write a query that gets the list of people who checked in to the class on a given day. The results from that query look something like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| person id | first name | last name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|      1234 | john       | smith     |
|      1235 | jane       | smith     |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

But what I need is an additional column that says how many times the particular person has attended that class within a 12 week period. So the results I want would look something like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| person id | first name | last name | attendance |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|      1234 | john       | smith     |          3 |
|      1235 | jane       | smith     |          5 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I can also get the proper results for the "attendance" column with a `COUNT` query. This query only works when I specify a person ID in the attendance table.

So I need a query that will take the person ids from the first query and figure out how many times that person has attended in the last 12 weeks and apply that to a column.

Additional information:
It needs to count how many times the person has attended that class in a 12 week period including the last Sunday.

It is always 12 weeks from the current date

I suppose it is possible they could have attended two classes in a day but all the classes are on a Sunday and it is unlikely enough that I do not need to account for this

It is all based on a Sunday so I guess the answer is 12 weeks from last Sunday.

Here's my query that returns the results of who checked in last Sunday:

```
SELECT
pb.person_id, pb.nick_name, pb.last_name, COS.occurrence_name, COS.occurrence_description, COS.date_created, COS.occurrence_type, COS.occurrence_id, sm.role_luid
FROM core_v_occurrence_service COS
JOIN core_occurrence_attendance oa ON oa.occurrence_id = COS.occurrence_id
JOIN core_v_person_basic pb ON pb.person_id = oa.person_id
JOIN smgp_member sm ON sm.person_id = OA.person_id
WHERE oa.attended = 1
AND COS.occurrence_type = 140
AND COS.date_created BETWEEN (DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE())) AND GETDATE()
AND sm.role_luid  IN (24,25, 28)
AND sm.group_id = 3
```

And here's the query that gives me the count of how many times someone has attended a class:

```
SELECT COUNT (oa.person_id)
FROM core_occurrence_attendance oa
JOIN core_v_occurrence_service COS on cos.occurrence_id = oa.occurrence_id
WHERE oa.person_id = 27276
AND oa.attended = 1
AND COS.occurrence_type = 140
AND COS.date_created BETWEEN (DATEADD(week,-12,GETDATE())) AND GETDATE()
```

Basically what I need is a query that count how many times a person's person id is entered into the attendance table. Because a person's person id will be entered into that table every time they attend the class.

Comment: you should post some sample data from the tables, not only the output format

Comment: Couple of questions to help find a good answer: 1) do you want the people who attended _this week_, plus a count of how many times they attended in the last twelve weeks, or the people who attended _any time in the last twelve weeks_? 2) is it always 'the last twelve weeks', or is it 'during a period starting on date _x_'?  3) could people attend different classes during that twelve week period, and if so do you need to show attendance separately? 4) is it 'twelve weeks from today' or 'twelve weeks from last Sunday'? Edit answers into the original question.

Comment: Please google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Comment: @vkp I do not want to post sample data for confidentially reasons.

@ AHiggns 1) it needs to count how many times the person has attended that class in a 12 week period including the last Sunday. 2) it is always 12 weeks from the current date 3) I suppose it is possible they could have attended two classes in a day but all the classes are on a Sunday and it is unlikely enough that I do not need to account for this 4) It is all based on a Sunday so I guess the answer is 12 weeks from last Sunday.

Comment: @NickTaylor Sample data avoids confidentiality issues by being fake, but realistic enough to allow developers to create a workable solution. Also - there is a really nice tool that lets you generate fake data. [Generate Data](http://www.generatedata.com/)

Comment: @vkp I might not understand you, but the data that is in my example results is just like the data I see in my actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!
I created a CTE for the query that counts the attendance.

I then did `SELECT DISTINCT` on that CTE and added a `GROUP BY` with all the column names.

I also added the date range of 12 weeks I needed in the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a group by into the query:

```
SELECT Person_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, COUNT(Person_ID) AS Attendance
FROM <YOURTABLE>
WHERE <DateField> BETWEEN <begindate> AND <enddate>
GROUP BY Attendance
```

The group by will count how many times that person has shown up for class and put it into one cell.

I a not guaranteeing this code runs because you post is missing some information.replace everything in the angle brackets.

Comment: `group by` should be on `Person_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME`

Comment: Yeah my bad I was writng off the cuff

Comment: Can I use this query as a subquery or something to the one I have already written to show who attended the class I am looking at?

Comment: This works, but only returns the results for the 1 week date range. I need just the attendance column to look at a 12 week period

Comment: Just put in the 12 week date range. Like BETWEEN 2015-01-01 AND 2015-03-01